# Gerar arquivo com nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho a seguinte problematica, possuo um conversor de xml to json em javascript e esse conversor guarda o objeto convertido em uma variável. Preciso adaptar esse código para que possibilite a escrita do arquivo a partir do nodejs, mas até o momento não consegui solucionar o problema.
Código do conversor:

```js
function XMLtoJSON() {
    var me = this; //
 
    me.fromFile = function(xml, rstr) {
        var xhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        // sets and sends the request for calling "xml"
        xhttp.open("GET", xml, false);
        xhttp.send(null);

        // gets the JSON string
        var json_str = jsontoStr(setJsonObj(xhttp.responseXML));

        return (typeof(rstr) == 'undefined') ? JSON.parse(json_str) : json_str;
    }

    me.fromStr = function(xml, rstr) {
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            var getxml = new DOMParser();
            var xmlDoc = getxml.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        } else {
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = "false";
        }

        var json_str = jsontoStr(setJsonObj(xmlDoc));
        return (typeof(rstr) == 'undefined') ? JSON.parse(json_str) : json_str;
    }

    var setJsonObj = function(xml) {
        var js_obj = {};
        if (xml.nodeType == 1) {
            if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
                js_obj["@attributes"] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                    var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                    js_obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.value;

                }
            }
        } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) {
            js_obj = xml.nodeValue;
        }
        if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
                var nodeName = item.nodeName;
                if (typeof(js_obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                    js_obj[nodeName] = setJsonObj(item);
                    if (nodeName == "child") {
                        //js_obj[nodeName] = setJsonObj(item);
                        js_obj[nodeName] = [];
                        js_obj[nodeName].push(old);
                        js_obj[nodeName].push(setJsonObj(item));
                    }

                } else {
                    if (typeof(js_obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {

                        var old = js_obj[nodeName];
                        js_obj[nodeName] = [];
                        js_obj[nodeName].push(old);
                    }
                    js_obj[nodeName].push(setJsonObj(item));
                }
            }
        }
        return js_obj;
    }


    var jsontoStr = function(js_obj) {
        var rejsn = JSON.stringify(js_obj, undefined, 2).replace(/(\\t|\\r|\\n)/g, '').replace(/"",[\n\t\r\s]+""[,]*/g, '').replace(/(\n[\t\s\r]*\n)/g, '').replace(/[\s\t]{2,}""[,]{0,1}/g, '').replace(/"[\s\t]{1,}"[,]{0,1}/g, '').replace(/\[[\t\s]*\]/g, '""').replace(/null,/g, '').replace(/[\\]/g, ' - ');
        return (rejsn.indexOf('"parsererror": {') == -1) ? rejsn : 'Invalid XML format';
    }
};

var xml2json = new XMLtoJSON();
```

Já tentei adicionar o seguinte código dentro desse js:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Porém ainda não obtive sucesso.
Logo na primeira linha me informa que o 'require' não está definido.
Alguem tem alguma luz para esse caso?
Pretendo criar um html com um botão e no clique do botao vai gerar o arquivo.

Comment: `require` não é disponivel no cliente/browser. Não está definido é retornado pelo servidor node?

Comment: retorna no console do navegador. hummm então como eu deveria fazer pro node pegar a variavel para gerar o arquivo ?

Comment: então, não ficou claro, voce está trabalhando no cliente ou no servidor? algumas funções para cliente que exitem no servidor podem ser possiveis usando webpack.

Comment: no momento está tudo local no meu pc, instalei o node e uso ele pra rodar minha aplicação.  Esse js esta no client, mas não sei como fazer essa requisição pelo server por exemplo.

Comment: fico muito amplo wesley, mas pra tentar te dar um norte, você vai precisar carregar o arquivo no front, no caso o xml, certo?! entao enviar os bytes dele para o back (node). Com o arquivo no back, voce consegue usar o `fs`. Pra ficar claro, a api File System do node você só via conseguir usar no node.

Comment: entendi lucas, bom muito obrigado vou pesquisar um pouco sobre. Tem pouco material ainda sobre node ai fico um pouco perdido mas já me deu uma opção pelo menos. obrigado.

Comment: faz isso. primeiro compreende a diferença entre o  front e o back e tenta só enviar o arquivo pro back. voce pode ir perguntando por partes aqui que agente te ajuda.